# Using Javascript in Blogger Theme

Tags: javascript, blogger, innerhtml

I try to add javascript innerHTML code for my blog in Blogger Theme, but it didn't working, this is my code :

```
<div id='icon'></div>
    <script>
      var url_img = <data:blog.postImageUrl/>;
      document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML = url_img ;
    </script>
```

How can I run this simple javascript code in Blogger Theme ?

Answer (score 1):

The Data Layout tag needs to be wrapped in quotes otherwise it will throw JavaScript errors. Also, to make sure that the `data:blog.postImageUrl` is not empty, we need to wrap the whole code with a conditional statement. The new code would look like -

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageUrl'>
  <div id='icon'></div>
  <script>
    var url_img = "<data:blog.postImageUrl/>";
    document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML = url_img ;
  </script>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Is this Code can put in **wherever** in blogger theme ?

Comment: Yes, you can put this code wherever you want in the blogger theme as `data:blog` dictionary is a globally define

Comment: Hi, url image didn't show inside div section, what wrong ?

Comment: Can you share the URL of the blog, where you are testing this code?

Comment: http://beritatigadua.blogspot.co.id/2017/05/editing-foto-nyeleneh.html

you can see in that link, view source and search with key compass

Comment: The code is working without issue. The problem is that the DIV with ID `icon` is wrapped by a DIV which has been hidden via CSS (`display:none`)

Answer (score -1):

`<script>`Tags inserted in other languages need to compile, can not directly output `java` or `php` code. For example (php):

```
<script>
    var img_url = <?php echo imgUrl ?>
</script>
```

Comment: your answer might be correct, if the question would be on a php base blogging system like wordpress, but blogger(.com) uses its own xml based syntax for the data. [Official Documentation](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en) and [Unofficial Documentation](http://template-data.blogspot.co.at/2017/05/posts.html).